# How do I run Serenity web tests in parallel with gradle?

Tags: selenium, gradle, thucydides, serenity-bdd

Can't figure out how to run Serenity web tests in parallel with gradle.
[Here](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_configuration_parallel_executing_with_jenkins) is an example with maven + jenkins. But I need the same thing with gradle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this by following the steps

Step 1: Create Suite file

Step 2: Enter the following task code in gradle

```
task runAParallelSuite(type: Test) {
    def forks =2
    exclude ('**/Library.java')
    println "The Maximum parallel is $forks"
    // uncomment maxParallelForks if you prefer to use the Gradle process forker
    // which also requires a complete change of how the suite class works
    maxParallelForks = forks
    include '**/**TestSuite.class'
    // testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/AParallelSuite")
    // testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/AParallelSuite")
    // show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

now run the command in cmd prompt `'gradle clean runAParallelSuite aggregate'`

Comment: Could you please explain me the Step 1? How should create a Suite file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this

```
   test {
       maxParallelForks=2
       options {
           systemProperties(System.getProperties())
       }
       ...
   }
```

[maxParallelForks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:maxParallelForks) allows to set maximum number of forked test processes to execute in parallel with jUnit